# MPXJ - get ResourceAssignment baseline values

Tags: ms-project, mpxj

I'm trying to display the Baseline Start, Finish, Cost, and Work values for a ResourceAssignment, but cannot seem to find any methods on the ResourceAssignment object that would provide this information. Anybody know if this is possible?

I know the information is stored because I can see it in MS Project, and I can see it in the XML version of the project file. Just can't see in the API where to get access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody cares, Jon has fixed this in the latest version of the MPXJ source code. You can see the bug request [here](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=528544&aid=2965334&group_id=70649).